# Different dns provider config on client and vpn provider causes Internet issue

Tags: vpn, dns, firewall, cisco-anyconnect

I tried connecting to my office network via VPN. When I just click on connect after providing all the credentials, the Internet across all the devices that are connected to the router would drop. The system is neither connected to my office network nor can I access the Internet. I then have to restart my router to get Internet again.

After researching a bit and testing around a few configurations, I was able to make it work by changing my DNS provider from "1.1.1.1" to "8.8.8.8"

Can anyone explain to me why this change made it work?

I tried to keep all the unnecessary information away, so if I missed something important, kindly let me know.

The OS is macOS and the software that I used to connect is Anyconnect (cisco).

Comment: What DNS server are those other devices configured to use?

Comment: Found a similar issue connecting through one public WiFi (using either Linux or Windows OS); changing DNS provider to "automatic", rather than CloudFlare, resolved the issue. This seemed to be ISP-dependent.

Comment: Most of them are android phones and iPhones, nothing explicitly configured. Router configuration is also not touched. so it either would be 8.8.8.8 or ISP DNS.